Why is LazyColumn's scroll super slow?
It's so slow, it's almost unusable. Release build  doesn't make much difference unless the the outerLists size is around 2
Tried: My searches did not yeild anything i can undertand. I tried looking for recomposition issues but cant seem to find anything inside the LazyColumn block.
Expecting: normal verticalScrolling like other apps or should feel  the same as the HorizontalScroll of this app.
// Use mutableStateListOf         
var data =  mutableStateListOf<List<CellData>>().apply { 
    // Initialize with some sample data (20 rows, 10 columns)         
    addAll(
        List(100) { outerIndex ->                 
            List(100) { innerIndex ->                     
                val value = "Value ${outerIndex * 10 + innerIndex + 1}"                                 
                CellData(value)
            }
        }
    )
}

fun Grid(data: List<List<CellData>>) {     
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()     
        //.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())                 
    ) {         
        itemsIndexed(data) { Outerindex:Int, row ->             
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()                    
                ) {                 
                    row.forEachIndexed {Innerindex: Int,  cell ->                                    

                        ExcelCell(cell, Outerindex, Innerindex )                 
                    }             
                }             
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))         
         }     
    } 
}

I observed that if i dsable the HorizontalScrolling, the verticalScrolling improves by a lot, becomes somewhat usable, but in this case, here is this weird thing that can be seen- the new row of elements which are about enter the viewport gets hit at the bottom of the screen, the scrolling speed becomes uneven, and again normal scrolling speed returns until another new row of elememts is about to enter the viewport.
Or to describe it in another term, before a new row of elements enter the screen, it feels like, something is happening with the row of elements just before they enter screen  which in turn causes slight delay and hence because of this sudden situation,  the scrolling speed decreases too fast   and a "bumpy/hit someting"  visuals & feel occurs.
